# Modifying %HOME% on Emacs 24.3 on Windows causes .emacs to not be found

Tags: windows, emacs

In order for magit to read my git settings on Emacs 24.3.1 for Windows, I added the following configuration from a [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18230505/85485):

```
(when (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
  (setenv "HOME" (concat (getenv "HOMEDRIVE") (getenv "HOMEPATH")))
```

Interestingly, after this is added to my .emacs, Emacs thinks .emacs doesn't exist anymore.

If I do M-x cd to ~ and then do M-x pwd it says ~ is located at C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming. It appears that emacs is reading the .emacs settings file because it loads my custom theme. However, if I try to find ~/.emacs Emacs doesn't see it. The file has all permissions on the file system for any user.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `Home` environment variable in Windows to the directory of your liking.

On Windows 8.1 I can access the environment variables from the Start screen typing

`Edit environment variables for your account`